# Dev-C++ (actually WxDev-C++ 7.4.2.569 - Project Inspector and Compiler log doesnt show

Tags: dev-c++

I can't find an answer. All was working fine when both my Project Inspector, Class Browser and Compiler log windows disappeared. Restarted WxDev - same thing. Reset computer - same thing. Load a new version of WxDecC++ in a new folder, same thing. Windows 7. Was working earlier in the day and no it is gone. No explanation of why they disappeared. Can't find the window potentially hidden behind other windows. I can't see compiler errors or files in a project or the classes defined.

Been wasting endless hours trying to track this down. Open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Could not track down why this happened. But, I went to appdata and removed the file called layout.ini and it restored the missing windows.